# Pandas export to_excel error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I use the following code to try and make a dataframe from a Tf-Idf vectorizer. The output of the vectorizer's fit_transform is a sparse matrix so I use toarray() to convert to array, and then pandas.DataFrame to convert to dataframe. I also extract the list of features using vectorizer.get_feature_names() and use that as column names for the dataframe.

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(text_list)
word_list = vect.get_feature_names()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray())
df1.to_excel("temp1.xlsx")

df2 = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns = word_list)
df2.to_excel("temp2.xlsx")
```

In case-1, the dataframe df1 gets exported with no problem. However the column names are missing - labeled 0,1,2 ...

In case-2, I try to include the column names, but the export throws an error.

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'

Funnily, this error happens only in some cases and not all. For different text data, this problem does not arise. So I think it may have something to do the word_list and maybe formatting.

After a bit more investigation, I found that one of the column names was "render" and that is creating the problem. How to I work around it? The following code throws the same error. df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], columns = ["render"]) followed by df.to_excel("temp.xlsx")

Can someone explain why?

Comment: After a bit more investigation, I found that one of the column names was "render" and that is creating the problem. How to I work around it? The following code throws the same error. df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], columns = ["render"]) followed by df.to_excel("temp.xlsx")

Comment: Solved it by passing column names as header parameter for the pandas.to_excel() rather than including it in the dataframe as column names.

Comment: Regarding your 1st comment - such additional info should be added to the post by editing & updating; regarding your 2nd comment - be kind enough & post it as an answer, so that it will be useful for others in the future

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by passing column names as header parameter for the pandas.to_excel() rather than including it in the dataframe as column names. Still not sure how to overcome this problem at the root and make it consider "render" as a proper column heading.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray())
df2.to_excel("temp2.xlsx", headers = word_list)
```